# Center second div which has higher z-index

Tags: css, html, append, center

I'm trying to centralise a div (boxTest) within a div which is 100% width and height fixed.

below is the code and here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/huddds/vYFxt/)

html

```
 <a href="#" class="clickme">CLICK ME</a>
```

jQuery

```
 $( function() {
    $(".clickme").click(function() {
    $('body').append('<div class="videoMask" style="position:fixed; top:0; bottom:0; z-index:14000000; left:0; right:0; width:100%; height:100%; background-color:#000000;"></div><div id="boxTest" style=" width:150px; background:#FFFFFF; position:fixed; top:10px; z-index:15000000; height:150px; margin:0; padding:0;"><span class="closeMe">CLOSE</span></div>');
    $('#boxTest').show();   
 });

     $( ".closeMe, .videoMask" ).live('click', function() {
        $( "#boxTest" ).remove(); 
        $( ".videoMask" ).remove();  
     });   
 });
```

P.s the in line styles will be changed, I did it this way to make it a little easier to see on here.

Thanks in advance for any responses.
​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try applying this style to #boxTest to center it horizontally...

```
#boxTest
{
    width:150px;
    position:absolute; /* OR FIXED IF THIS WORKS BETTER FOR YOU */
    margin-left:-75px;
    left:50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its difficult to fix a DIV within another having width in percentage. I edited the CSS as following and it seems to be properly center aligned.

http://jsfiddle.net/vYFxt/21/

**CSS**

```
.videoMask
{
    vertical-align:middle;
    z-index:14000000;
    width:500px;
    height:400px;
    background-color:#000;
    display:table-cell;
}

#boxTest
{
    width:150px;
    background:#FFF;
    z-index:15000000;
    height:150px;
    margin:auto;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    $(".clickme").click(function() {
        $('body').append('<div class="videoMask"><div id="boxTest" ><span class="closeMe">CLOSE</span></div></div>');
        $('#boxTest').show();
    });

    $(".closeMe, .videoMask").live('click', function() {
        $("#boxTest").remove();
        $(".videoMask").remove();
    });
});​
```

Comment: The boxTest div isn't inside the other div (videoMask) it just has a higher z-index, does it not make it a little easier? or is it the fixing of the videoMask that stops margin:0 auto working on boxTest?

Comment: Also in the fiddle linked above the popup now closes if the white area is clicked and in mine it needs to only close is the mask or close are clicked as in my original fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/vYFxt/23/) may be more help to you. That's a lot of code within the jQuery, too much really

```
$(function() {
  $(".clickme, .closeme").click(function() {
    $('.clickme').toggle();  
    $('.videoMask').toggle();  
  });
});
```

​

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned, it will have a video in it for mp4 and flash for non compatible so it needs to be removed of the video carries on playing.